# ASP Help Desk Script

Tags: iis

I need a help desk ticket & live chat system for my company web site. I was using the script on http://www.helpcenterlive.com/ previously. But it s a php script and now my website works ona windows server and i need to find asp version or alternative of it. I will be appreciated for your anwers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the server, Windows runs PHP just fine.